# add existing RKE cluster to new Rancher installation

Tags: rancher, rancher-rke

We have k8s cluster which has Rancher 2.5.13 installed.
Someday we lost the server with Rancher. Rancher was installed on server. k8s cluster work normal, we can deploy some pod and etc.

On new server with same IP I'm installing new Rancher and registering existing kubernetes cluster.
All work fine except i can't add new node to kubernetes with Rancher UI (just not registration command in UI).

How can I add new worker nod to my k8s cluster if new Rancher doesn't provide registration command?

In docker container rancher-agent logs I'm seeing that they can't connect to rancher because selfsigned certificate not the same.